# Show that $e^x+\sin x$ hasn't minimum in $\mathbb{R}$ only with limits and continuity

Tags: limits, analysis, continuity

My analysis problems book proposes the problem: "Show that the function $f(x)=e^x+\sin x$ haven't minima in $\mathbb{R}$." in the section of "Limits and continuity", so I assume that this exercise must be solved without any further analysis techniques.

I've tried this: $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ because it is a sum of continuous functions in $\mathbb{R}$; moreover, since $e^x>0$ and $\sin x \geq -1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, it is $e^x+\sin x>-1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence $-1$ is a lower bound for $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
Define $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n:=\frac{3}{2}\pi-2n\pi$, it is
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[e^{3\pi/2-2n\pi}+\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-2n\pi\right)\right]=-1$$
Since there aren't $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)=-1$  because $e^x+\sin x>-1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, it is $\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{f(x)\}=-1$ and the infimum do not equals the minimum. I think that this shows that $f$ has no minima in $\mathbb{R}$, because the function can get arbitrarily close to $-1$ but never assume the value $-1$, so any value of $f$, no matter how close to $-1$, always has another value lesser than it because of the fact that $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary in the definition of limit.

The problem is that I'm not sure where I used the continuity of $f$, so the possibilities are that:

i) I haven't used the hypothesis of continuity or my reasoning for deducing that $f$ has no minimum is wrong, hence my solution is wrong or the problem assumes more hypothesis than needed;

ii) I have used it and I'm not seeing where. In this case, I only thought that I'm implicitly using the continuity of $f$ to evaluate the limit of $f(x_n)$ in the following way: $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right)$.

Can someone tell me if I've done some mistakes or this is correct because of what I say in (ii)? Or for other reasons. Thanks for the help.

Comment: “Does not equal the minimum” is not an ideal statement, since there is no minimum. “The infimum is not a minimum” is a more accurate statement.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Thanks for correcting me, I was not happy of that statement as well but I didn't knew a proper way to say it. Now I know it thanks to you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't used the continuity of $f$, and it is not needed either. Essentially what you did was you showed that $f(x)>-1$ for all $x$ and that for some sequence $(x_n)_n$ you have $f(x_n) \to -1$ as $n \to \infty$. These two facts alone imply that $f$ does not attain a minimum, for any minimum would have to be larger than $-1$ since $f(x) > -1$, but any value $m>-1$ cannot be a minimum since for large enough $n$, $f(x_n)$ would be between $m$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative we could proceed by contradiction, suppose minimum at $x_0$ exists then

$$e^{x_0}+\sin x_0=m_0$$

but for $x_1=x_0-2\pi$ we have

$$m_1=e^{x_1}+\sin x_1 =\frac{e^{x_0}}{e^{2\pi}}+\sin x_0<e^{x_0}+\sin x_0=m_0$$

which is a contradiction.